# Azure Blob Storage returns 404 on PUT

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I created new blob storage; set CORS to allow all (*) origins; created new container (dev); set container access policy to "Container". Now when I'm trying to upload file (file.txt) to my container I get 404 ResourceNotFound "The specified resource does not exist." response.
I make following request from Postman:

```
PUT /dev/file.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
x-ms-date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 09:00:00 GMT
x-ms-version: 2015-02-21
x-ms-blob-content-type: text/plain
```

What might be a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> set container access policy to "Container"

Setting container access policy to `Container` will only work for read operations. For write operations, the requests need to be authenticated.

For authentication, you would need to create an `Authorization` header as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx.

An alternative to that is to make use of `Shared Access Signature (SAS)`. What you need to do is create a `SAS Token` with at least `Write` permission and create a SAS URL with that token (which is your blob url + SAS token). Please see this link for more details about Shared Access Signature: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/.