# Uploading blob to Azure with Unity

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine

I am trying to upload data to a blob service on Azure portal.

I have been trying to use this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179451.aspx

The code I have is the following:

```
IEnumerator SetItem ()
{
    DataJson data = new DataJson("Amy", "201289");
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);
    UnityWebRequest newWWW = UnityWebRequest.Put(
        "https://compstorage.blob.core.windows.net/folderName/item", json);
    yield return newWWW.Send();
    if (newWWW.isError == false)
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
    }
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("compstorage.blob.core.windows.net/folderName/item.json");
    yield return www.Send();
    string text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(www.downloadHandler.data);
    DataJson newData = JsonUtility.FromJson<DataJson>(text);
    Debug.Log(newData.ToString()); 
}
```

The blob is set as Blob meaning read, write permission. I tried all kind of variations like adding/removing file extension, also adding the SaS key but it never updates the server content despite the Put request claiming to be successful. The Get request does work fine but prints old version of data, not the updated one.

Does anyone know the way to use the Put request in Unity

Comment: Are you getting any error message back from Azure Storage?

Comment: None, it goes fine. I tried to read the content from uploadHandler but nothing.

Comment: That's weird! Usually there should be some error reported back from Azure Storage. One thing though: Setting container's ACL as `Blob` will not help in this case. Please see this thread for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40017960/azure-blob-storage-returns-404-on-put/40018175#40018175. You mentioned that you tried with SAS as well. Did your SAS has `Write` permission?

Comment: It has them all. I tried to append the SAS but nothing happens. I guess I must be missing one thing somewhere. I 'll keep trying.

Comment: You might find this sample Unity project showing various PUT authenticated blob requests useful - https://github.com/Unity3dAzure/StorageServicesDemo

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell why this is happening but you can use [this](https://github.com/dgkanatsios/AzureServicesForUnity) plugin to communicate with your Azure service. It will solve your problem.

**EDIT**:

After reading the MS link you posted, the problem is that you are missing several headers:

- Authorization
- Date or x-ms-date
- x-ms-version
- Content-Length
- x-ms-blob-type

Please understand that there types of blob. You did not mention the type of blob request you are making. Please see that [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179451.aspx) again to see which extra headers are needed for each blob. If it says "Required" in the description then you must include it in the request. You don't need it if it says "Optional".

How do you include headers with `UnityWebRequest` ?

```
UnityWebRequest newWWW = UnityWebRequest.Put("https://compstorage.blob.core.windows.net/folderName/item", json);
newWWW.SetRequestHeader("Authorization","your Authorization");
newWWW.SetRequestHeader("x-ms-version","v1");
newWWW.SetRequestHeader("x-ms-blob-type","BlockBlob");
newWWW.SetRequestHeader("x-ms-date","Your Datte");
```

Don't worry about the `Content-Length` and `Date` headers as Unity will automatically generate them for you. You are not allowed to set them manually with `UnityWebRequest` anyways. Look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/f1d0538f-e4ae-44cd-9ca0-db58eb6b1338/notification-hub-authentication-errors?forum=notificationhubs) for what to put for the authorization header.

Comment: Uploading blob is a `PUT` request and not a `PATCH` request.

Comment: Just noticed that. Fixed!

Comment: I'll have a deeper look but at first glance, it seems to be a rewrite of the UnityWebRequest class. Mostly, I need a PUT request, but this seems to be for GET/POST and tables. I'll see.

Comment: @Everts Hey take a look the edited answer. It should take you to the path to solve your problem.

Comment: Yep, basically it is my authorization that is wrong. I need to figure out how to populate that field. Seems I should create a string of info, convert it with some HMAC-SHA256 and then pass it on.

Comment: If you use Shared Access Signature (SAS), then you don't need to set all these headers as this information is included there. Will it be possible to share what your SAS Token looks like?

Comment: I have tried to happen the SAS. It is the classic SAS with all permissions. I will give it another try tho.